# Threejs loaders not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, 3d, three.js, webgl

I have been using three.js to put a 3D model on the web but it seems that the loaders provided in the library are not working in chrome. They work perfectly in Firefox though. I checked that I have the latest version of chrome and even checked that webgl is enabled in chrome.
Can somebody tell me what could be wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the same-origin policy is the issue (like Abstract Algorithm suggested), you can also use an IDE for development, which starts a local web server. Visual Studio Express and Adobe Brackets come to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Make sure that you run Chrome with *--allow-file-access-from-files* flag.

Hope this solves your problem.